# Projection on an Equality constrained set.

Tags: linear-algebra

This might be a simple question but I just cannot formualte a general formula.

Say I define a set:

$$S = \{x:Ax=b\}$$ where $A$ is full rank. Then what will be the projection of any general point $y$ on this set $S$ i.e find $x^*$ such that $Ax^*=b$ and distance between $x^*$ and $y$ is minimum.

Comment: If A has full rank then Ax = b has a unique solution by the invertible matrix theorem, so only one choice for x^*.

Comment: @Countable No full rank doesn't mean it has to be a square matrix. It means rank in one dimension is full.

Comment: ah ok my bad---